# Openssl for RSA: undefined reference to RSA_new

Tags: c, unix, openssl

I've starto today to explore openSSL api for RSA. That's the simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<openssl/rsa.h>
#include<openssl/engine.h>
int main() {
    RSA *rsa;
    rsa = RSA_new_();
    RSA_free(rsa);
    return 0;
}
```

and i'm compiling with

> gcc -I /usr/local/ssl/include -o etc etc

but gcc return error of undefining reference to RSA_new and RSA_free. I've check the rsa.h header, and there's no reference to this two function. 
what's wrong? 
I've follow the reference guide on openssl website...

EDIT: 
gcc output:

> gcc -I /usr/local/ssl/include/ -o rsa rsa.c -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lcrypto 
>   /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to`dlopen'
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `dlsym'
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to`dlclose'
>   /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_func':
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x3b1): undefined reference to`dlsym'
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x490): undefined reference to `dlerror'
>   /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function`dlfcn_bind_var':
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x511): undefined reference to `dlsym'
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x5f0): undefined reference to`dlerror'
>   /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_load':
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x667): undefined reference to`dlopen'
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x6de): undefined reference to `dlclose'
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x715): undefined reference to`dlerror'
>   /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x7b1): undefined reference to`dladdr'
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x819): undefined reference to `dlerror'
>   /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function`dlfcn_unload':
>   dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x87a): undefined reference to `dlclose'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You need to link with the library for `ssl`. I am not sure what its name is but try adding `-lssl` to end of your compiler command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The propblem is that you are linking with `libssl` and you are using RSA crypto which is part of `libcrypto`, another error : there is no function called : `RSA_new_`:

```
toc@UnixServer:/usr/include/openssl$ grep RSA_new *
rsa.h:RSA * RSA_new(void);
rsa.h:RSA * RSA_new_method(ENGINE *engine);
```

So correct your code:

```
rsa = RSA_new();
```

And compile like that:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/openssl/ -Wall my_rsa.c -o my_rsa  -lcrypto
```

**EDIT : for the last error(dl functions):**

```
gcc -I/usr/include/openssl/ -Wall my_rsa.c -o my_rsa  -lcrypto -ldl
```

Comment: perfect. I've just add the -L options at the end for path of library files. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to link with the library as well:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include -o etc etc.c -L/usr/local/lib -lssl
```

The `-L` option tells GCC where to look for library file, and `-l` (small L) tells the linker that it should link with the library.

Replace the library folder and library name with what you got.

Answer (score 2):

You have to *link against* the libSSL library. Something like

```
gcc -I /usr/local/ssl/include -o myprog myprog.c -lssl
```

will do the trick.

(Maybe it's not actually `-lssl` but `-lopenssl`, `-lssl-rsa` or whatever; you can find this out by typing

```
pkg-config --libs PACKAGENAME
```

where PACKAGENAME is the name of the package which contains libssl, something like libssl, openssl, libssl-dev, openssl-devel etc.)

Comment: i've try to do that, but it doesn't still work!
the directory /usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig contains three files:
libcrypto.pc, libssl.pc, openssl.pc. I'm compiling but something gone wrong. I edit the main message with the compiling output

Comment: "...to do that" - to do what?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `-lssl` or something like that. 'Undefined reference' is generated by the linker, which is looking for the actual implementation of `RSA_new` and `RSA_free`. Those functions are located somewhere in the openssl library, and with `-lssl` you let the linker know where they are.

EDIT: if there would be something wrong with the header file you would see an error like 'implicit declaration of identifier RSA_new'. But you need to enable certain flags to have that kind of errors (I thought `-Wmissing-prototypes`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

`gcc <other args> -lcrypto`

Which tells the compiler to include and link with the crypto header files.

This works if you are using openssl i.e. `#include <openssl/bn.h>`

Answer (score 0):

If you use CMakeLists.txt, you must add this simple command:

```
link_libraries(ssl  crypto)
```